# ANTLR: Testing the equivalence of tagname in start and endtag

Tags: xml, grammar, antlr3

I have a problem building a grammar with ANTLR v3
using antlrworks-1.5.2-complete.
I am looking for a grammar rule representing an XML-element.
The equivalence of the tagnames in start- and endtag must be tested (well-formedness).

In the article [Parsing XML](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Parsing+XML) a solution of the Problem is given,
but I would prefer a simpler way as e.g. possible with Perl (RecDescent) or yacc/bison.

With the Perl module Parse::RecDescent the problem can be solved by a rule

```
element:  '<' name attributes '>' content '</' "$item[2]" '>'
```

the `$item[2]` carries the string, found by the symbol name (2. part of the production).

Does such a simple reference as `$item[2]` or `$2` (in yacc) exist in ANTLR too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does such a simple reference as $item[2] or $2 (in yacc) exist in ANTLR too?

No.

In ANTLR, one would validate this when walking the (parse) tree, or inside the grammar using a predicate:

```
element
 : '<' open=NAME attributes '>' content '</' close=NAME '>'
   {$open.text.equals($close.text)}?
 ;

attributes
 : (NAME '=' STRING)+
 ;

content
 : ...
 ;

NAME
 : 'a'..'z'+ // not complete, of course!
 ;
```

Comment: This predicate looks good understandable for beginners too, thank you. Can the thrown exception be used for a behaviour, that the rule `element` doesn't match `<a> ... </b>` and the parse tree will be rolled back before the `<a>`?

Comment: I've not tried such a thing before, but for more info about error recovery, see: http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Custom+Syntax+Error+Recovery